# Color Clicker Inaccurate

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, bitmap

I am trying to write a program that clicks on the first pixel it finds which has a certain color. Unfortunately, it appears that sometimes my program is unable to detect that there is actually the color on the screen. I am taking a screenshot of the screen and then using the GetPixel() method to find the color of every pixel.

Here is my method I use:

```
private static Point FindFirstColor(Color color)
{
    int searchValue = color.ToArgb();
    Point location = Point.Empty;

    using (Bitmap bmp = GetScreenShot())
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                if (searchValue.Equals(bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()))
                {
                    location = new Point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

In order to take a screenshot of my screen, I use:

```
private static Bitmap GetScreenShot()
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        {
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                gfx.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Even when I use a color which I know is on the screen, it still returns Point.Empty. What is the reason for this?

Comment: May you please provide what `GetScreenShot()` exactly does? :)

Comment: If you need the first matching pixel, why don't you break out of loop after getting first match..?

Comment: I am still having problems with inaccuracy. When I run it once, it detects the color; at other times, it does not... I am not changing any code in between these runs. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just copied your method and used as color the find `Color.Black` and it worked without any problems.

The only thing that's currently maybe not correctly in your code is that you don't immediately return after finding the first matching point. Instead you simply continue to iterate over all points thus leading to the fact that you'll going to return the last occurrence of a matching color.

To avoid this you can change your code into:

```
private static Point FindFirstColor(Color color)
{
    int searchValue = color.ToArgb();

    using (Bitmap bmp = GetScreenShot())
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                if (searchValue.Equals(bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb()))
                {
                    return new Point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Point.Empty;
}
```